# How to get complete URL in Owin Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I want to get **XYZClient** from url: https://companyabc.com/stockapp/XYZClient/login in owin startup.cs,MVC ASP.net.

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(companyABC.Web.Startup))]
namespace companyABC.Web
{
    public partial class Startup 
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder builder) 
        {
            throw new Exception(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()); 
            //gets companyabc.com/stockapp only. I want to get companyabc.com/stockapp/XYZClient/login 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.Url gets https://companyabc.com/stockapp/

Comment: Is it webforms, MVC? How is the path formed? Do you always want the second-to-last word? Can the url be .../XYZClient/Section/Page?

Comment: its MVC,request comes like url as mentioned.i want to get XYZClient from url.There is is no /Section in that..

Comment: Given what you have explained, this is the easiest approach: `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Substring(32, 9)`

Comment: thanks addrew,But in owin startup class i am unable to get the complete url using HttpContext.Current.Request.Url. Its give me https://companyabc.com/stockapp only, Based on the url segment[2] i need to hook some logic in iis request pipeline.

Comment: You may have to give more details about what you need. You may need to use `BeginRequest` in Global.asax.cs.

Comment: can you give more details of what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: still there? Can you give more details of what your final goal is?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What about any of these?

```
Request.Url.Segments[2]
Request.Url.LocalPath.Split('/')[2]
```

Comment: Andrew, the problem is in the startup.cs request.url gives https://companyabc.com/stockapp instead of "https://companyabc.com/stockapp/XYZClient/login".

Comment: Right, because the web server is just starting, before any request. You need to give more details of what you want to do.

Comment: based on XYZClient of url i want to configure SSO.

Comment: You should really add the code to the question and not in a comment. Do you think it is understandable this way? Check [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).